# Can't launch browser with Selenium Remote Driver

Tags: perl, selenium

I don't know why but I cannot launch browser using the below code. I am using EPIC on eclipse. I have installed required selenium modules for this.

I get this error when I run below mentioned code: "Could not connect to SeleniumWebDriver at C:/ProgramFiles/Perl/site/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 220"

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

`use Selenium::Remote::Driver;`

```
my $driver = new Selenium::Remote::Driver(browser_name => 'firefox', port => 5555,
                                          platform => 'WINDOWS');
$driver->get('http://www.google.com');
print $driver->get_title();
$driver->quit();
```

Comment: Is selenium actively listening on port 5555 of localhost? That error means your program cannot find the selenium server.

Comment: How would I make sure that its listening to port 5555? If my programm cannot find selenium server, is it related to permission issue or may be the path mentioned is wrong to the perl.

Comment: I found out the reason but now I don't know why it gives blank page as it should open google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the Selenium version to 2.31 and it worked. Previously I was using 2.28 which had incompatibility with FF 19

Answer (score 2):

It might be closing the page before you notice it? Also, I think by default the port number selenium listens on is `4444`.

Try this:

```
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;


my $driver = new Selenium::Remote::Driver(browser_name => 'firefox', port => 4444,
                                          platform => 'ANY',);
$driver->get('http://www.google.com');
sleep(200);
print $driver->get_title(),"\n";
$driver->quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Charles, my PC was updated with new Java version and so my server start up file was failing to start the server. I corrected the start up file with correct java path and it launches the browser.

But I don't know why it gives blank page as it should open google.com

Comment: I changed the Selenium version to 2.31 and it worked. Previously I was using 2.28 which had incompatibility with FF 19

Answer (score 0):

before run the code you should start the remote server.
Enter the path as below where your chrome driver and jar file are exited in your system and

Go to the command prompt an run the following command- please

java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="\Enter folder path\chromedriver.exe" -jar \Enter folder path\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar

and if you are using Firefox then write the following code.
my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new();

for chrome user following - 
my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new(browser_name => 'chrome');